# Selecting/Unselecting all items in a Listview

Tags: android

I am using a multi select listview in my application. Specifically the simple_list_item_activated_1.

I have some of code, a button, that will select all the listview items. I have some logic saying that if all the items are already selected then deselect all the items.

When I press the button the first time, it will select all the items in the list as expected. and when I press the button a second time it deselects all the items as expected.

Here is my problem: 
When I press the button for a third time "selectedCount" still equals "childCount". So obviously my code will never enter the If statement.

Would anyone know why this is happening? or maybe there is a better way to do what im trying to achieve?

```
  int childCount = officerList.getChildCount();
  int selectedCount = officerList.getCheckedItemPositions().size();

            if(childCount != selectedCount){
                for (int i = 0; i < officerList.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    officerList.setItemChecked(i, true);
                }
            }else{
                for (int i = 0; i < officerList.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    officerList.setItemChecked(i, false);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to answer my own question. Using getCheckItemPositions().size() is an unreliable way of achieving what I want.

This will return a sparseBooleanArray() of all Items checked, so the first time it works correctly as initially there is nothing selected so it will return 0. Then once everything is selected the sparseBooleanArray will be equal to all the items in the list as they were all selected.

However as I learned spareBooleanArray is an Array that stores the position and a Boolean flag of if it is selected or not. In my scenario when I press the select all button for the third, the size of the array is still equal to number of list items.

How I have fixed my issue, is to use getCheckedItemCount() which only returns the number of selected items as I originally wanted. hopefully this answer will help someone else.

```
 int childCount = officerList.getChildCount();
 int selectedCount = officerList.getCheckedItemCount();

        if(childCount != selectedCount){
            for (int i = 0; i < officerList.getChildCount(); i++) {
                officerList.setItemChecked(i, true);
            }
        }else{
            for (int i = 0; i < officerList.getChildCount(); i++) {
                officerList.setItemChecked(i, false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic, it will check all the items if none of the items are checked, else will check only the items which are unchecked and vice versa.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
       SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = officerList.getCheckedItemPositions();
       if(sparseBooleanArray != null && sparseBooleanArray.size() >0) {
            for (int index = 0; index < sparseBooleanArray.size(); index++) {
                if(sparseBooleanArray.valueAt(index)){
                        officerList.setItemChecked(sparseBooleanArray.keyAt(index),true);
                    }
                    else {
                        officerList.setItemChecked(sparseBooleanArray.keyAt(index),false);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                for (int index = 0; index < officerList.getCount(); index++) {
                    officerList.setItemChecked(index,true);
                }
            }
        }
```